I've got a Joomla site that uses JCE but keep getting double lines on tables on PDFs
I've got a site that uses the Calcbuilder component to generate drawings from customer input. I use JCE pro in the backend of my site.
My problem is that even though my tables show up fine on the screen, SOME of the lines are doubled when the user exports to PDF.
Does someone have any idea what I should add or remove from my HTML to fix this?
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><img src="images/4_to_6_high_with_bottom_wire_in_concrete.jpg" alt="4 to 6 high with bottom wire" width="700" height="335" style="float: left;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><span style="font-size: 8pt;"></span>
                <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><strong>Specification:</strong></span></p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Fence to be ##FenceHeight## high.</span></p>
                <p><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Terminal posts to be ##TerminalPosts## mild steel tubing, installed at each end, corner, and gate in ##TerminalPostConcreteDiameter## inch diameter by ##TerminalPostConcreteDepth## inch deep concrete footings.</span></p>
                <p><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Terminal posts will be fitted with steel tension bands at approximately 12-inch centers to accommodate tension bars.</span></p>
                <p><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Line posts to be ##LinePosts## spaced at ##LinePostSpacing## foot centers and installed in ##LinePostConcreteDiameter## inch diameter by ##LinePostConcreteDepth## inch deep concrete footings.</span></p>
                <p><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Terminal posts are to have dome caps, and line posts are to have eye tops/loop caps of sufficient size to cover the top of each post completely and prevent water ingress.</span></p>
                <p><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Chain link fabric to be ##ChainLinkFenceFabricType##, with a ##ChainLinkFabricFinish## with a matching ##BottomWireType## and ##FittingMaterial## fittings.</span></p>
                <p><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Fence ties to match the fence are to be installed at ##TieWireSpacing## inch centers, and hog rings to attach fence fabric to the bottom wire to be spaced at ##HogRingSpacing## inches.</span></p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12pt;">##FenceColor## ##ProjectType## Chain Link Fence ##FenceHeight## High</span></strong></td>
            <td rowspan="6" style="border: 1px solid #000000; vertical-align: top;">
                <p><strong><span style="font-size: 12pt;">##CompanyName##</span></strong></p>
                <span style="font-size: 8pt;">##CompanyWebsite##</span><br /><span style="font-size: 8pt;">##CompanyPhoneNumber##</span><br /><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Prepared By: ##PreparedBy##</span><br /><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Email: ##ContactEmail##</span><br /><span style="font-size: 8pt;">##Date##</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Client Name: ##ClientName##</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Project Name: ##ProjectName##</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Drawing Number: ##DrawingNumber##</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Revision Number: ##RevisionNumber##</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><span style="font-size: 8pt;">Scale: NTS</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

I tried changing the table cellspacing to 0, but that's not working on all the lines.
Tried using the JCE table properties to edit the lines, but that's REALLY bad and doesn't really do anything.
